# Probe status code mismatch. Received status code is different from expected 200-399

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I set up health probes in Azure Application Gateway yet get the above error? I followed the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-probe-portal  but to no avail. I am using App gateway to load balance to web apps not VMS

Answer (score 1):

That means your webapp returns code that is greater than 399 (404 or 403 or 500). You need to fix this issue and the probe will consider your webapp healthy.

Comment: well, i dont know what is wrong with your webapp, but you should just look at the error you are getting and fix it. one way to understand is to go to the application gateway on the portal and open `backend health` blade, and look at the error text

Comment: I can access the webapp ok via the direct link azure allocates it but when I use my hostname eg www.mydomain.com which has a cname pointing to the app gateway  it gives a 404 error so I know the web app is ok which is why I'm puzzled

Comment: what do you mean its OK if it returns 404 when you use the `mydomain.com` url. like i said, you need to fix this 404 and the app gateway will work, or reconfigure app gateway to use azure "direct link" and cname mydomain.com to application gateway

Comment: The cname already points to the appgateway , the listener is set up to listen for traffic on port 80 for www.mydonain.com, this then has a rule. Associated to a backend pool pointing to the azure webapp. I can't see why it's giving a 404 error.

Comment: it is really not possible to help you given this level of detail

Comment: I have a listener set up as follows :

Comment: @itye1970 Did you figure this out? I have also the exact problem.